# Why use double parentheses in init methods, or is 1 == (1)?

Tags: objective-c, c

What do parentheses do when evaluating some meaning?
I have faced this in code, when something is checked and they use

```
if ( (some condition that returns 1) )
{
code
}
```

So my question is, does this evaluate to true? I would think that it is always false since (1) does not return anything?

Edit: clarification, question is why double parenthesis in if? I know that 1 is true.

Comment: Probably more for readability.

Comment: In lots of init method you see... `if ( (self = [super init]) ) {}` I never understood the meaning of two sets of parentheses.

Comment: `(1)` is not a function. It doesn't "return" anything any more than `1` does.

Comment: @Fogmeister exactly, that code made me ask this question

Comment: @Juhana ok, so (((((1))))) == 1 ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The additional parentheses are used when an assignment is used for its truth value. They allow the compiler to distinguish between

```
if ((var = expr))
```

which signals **intentional** combination of assignment and truth value test, and

```
if (var = expr)
```

as an unintentional misspelling of `if (var == expr)`.

The convention, carried over from C and C++, is for the compilers to warn on `if (var = expr)` as a possible misspelling of `if (var == expr)`. They don't warn on `if ((var = expr))`, because the extra set of parentheses signals to the compiler that the assignment was intended. As rob mayoff explains, clang has a special case not to warn for certain assignments to `self`, but for many coders the habit remained.

As others said, the generated code is exactly the same with and without the extra parens.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you, I have heard that compiler gives warnings in such cases, forgot about that.

Comment: You will **not** get a warning under default build settings if you say `if (self = [super init])`, because clang explicitly recognizes that case and suppresses the warning by default.  See [`Sema::DiagnoseAssignmentAsCondition` in the clang source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Sema/SemaExpr.cpp#L11514).  Some people got in the habit before clang had the special case (I guess), but it's not necessary anymore when reassigning `self` during initialization.

Comment: @robmayoff I've amended the answer to include this info, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you write,

```
if (self = [super init]) { // Warning
    // ...
}
```

The compiler will give you a warning, because it thinks you might have mistyped `=` as `==`.  If you add a second set of parentheses, the warning goes away.

```
if ((self = [super init])) { // No warning
    // ...
}
```

So the extra parentheses are there to make typos less likely.  The parentheses do not change the value of the expression.

Comment: Like any warning, this warning is by no means mandatory to give by any compiler. And from a functional compiler's point-of-view, it really doesn't make any sense to add an additional parenthesis. I'd say that any compiler removing the warning in case of an additional parenthesis is flawed or broken.

Comment: @Lundin: Thank you for pontificating on this topic.  It's always helpful to have more people voicing their opinions on how GCC and Clang are "broken", without explaining why.

Comment: I just explained why. What part of my comment is it that you don't understand? Or do you actually expect a compiler to change it's internal warning level depending on the number of sub-expressions the programmer has written inside a particular expression?

Comment: @Lundin: That sounds like a terrible way to implement this warning.  As a compiler writer myself, I would perform a check on each predicate and not recurse into subexpressions: you'd get the desired behavior without modifying internal state.  Every warning a compiler emits needs a delicate balance between false positives and false negatives, and benefits from small tricks to disable the warning locally like how `(void) x;` suppresses unused variable warnings.  Or you could just turn the warning off, instead of whining here about how GCC/Clang are "flawed/broken".  It's not productive.

Comment: "That sounds like a terrible way to implement this warning." Indeed! Then we agree. As for which compiler that is broken or not, I haven't named a single one, but refer to whatever it is the OP is using (some Objective C compiler).

Comment: I agree with @Lundin.  It's a ***broken*** warning because this code does not produce a warning:  `if ( ( a = b ) || ( c == d ) )`.  There's an expectation that `-Wparenthesis` will warn about the inadvertent use of an assignment operator in place of a comparison operator.  Pontificate all you want about this warning, but a warning that says it will do something that it then ***fails*** to do is worse than useless - it's harmful.  "If I make a mistake this warning will catch it."  **No, it won't** for anything other than trivial code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Why are you having this discussion here, rather than on a GCC mailing list or something?

Comment: @DietrichEpp Because your answer is ***here***, and it categorically states "The compiler will give you a warning".  I've demonstrated your answer is wrong.  The compiler will not give you a warning for anything but trivial code.  You could even say I've demonstrated the compiler in question is, ummm, broken.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Scroll a little farther up... you'll see that you're not even quoting a complete sentence. You've either misread or misinterpreted the answer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Your full sentence is "The compiler will give you a warning, because it thinks you might have mistyped = as ==."  So then why doesn't GCC warn on `if ( ( a = b ) || ( c == d ) )` if what you posted is true?  That full sentence in your answer is ***wrong***.  I didn't quote the full sentence because it's not necessary.  Safey-related standards such a MISRA require parenthesis, and GCC won't warn about a mistyped `=` instead of a `==` in all but trivial code. That - and your answer - creates a false sense of confidence in developers that a ***broken*** tool would otherwise save them

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Again, you are not quoting a complete sentence. The complete sentence contains a code block in the middle of it. Honestly I'm somewhat upset and frustrated by your behavior here.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: To be honest, I haven't been this unhappy with an interaction on Stack Overflow in at least a few years. Saying that my answer "creates a false sense of confidence" seems doesn't seem like an appropriate or rational reaction to what I said "makes typos less likely", and I can't make heads nor tails of why you would refuse to consider including the first half of a sentence in a quote.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Your example is trivial code.  If the code gets more complex, the warning is not emitted, as with `if ( ( a = b ) || ( c == d ) )`.  And the more complex the code, the harder it is for a human to spot the error.  Your answer states that the "compiler **will** give you a warning", but the code I just provided demonstrates that the compiler **will not** give that warning all the time.  Anyone reading GCC's documentation or this answer will believe that `-Wparenthesis` will spot inadvertent assignment in an `if` statement, but that's only true for trivial code - the warning is broken

Comment: @AndrewHenle: People with even a rudimentary understanding of English normally understand the construction "If X, then Y will Z." I don't know why you are having such a hard time understanding this sentence, but I don't think your misunderstanding is common enough to warrant clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241793/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-andrew-henle).

Answer (score 2):

In general 0 equates to false, NOT 0 to true.

This link explains bool in objective-c: http://www.mindsizzlers.com/2010/04/objective-c-and-the-properties-of-bool/

Comment: Thanks, but question is mainly about double parenthesis.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. Parenthesis are used to dictate the order in which operations are performed, so multiple parenthesis should not make a difference to the final condition evaluated, i.e. (((((1))))) == 1

Answer (score 1):

### true and false value of `bool` and `int`

- boolean value of `false` is equivalent to the `int` value of `0`.
- boolean value of `true` is equivalent to the `int` value of non-zero (e.g. `1`, `10`, `3000`, etc)

For example, consider an example of C code below:

```
bool bValue;
int nValue;

bValue = true;
nValue = 1;

if (bValue == nValue) {
    printf("bValue and nValue are the same!\n");
}

// output: bValue and nValue are the same!
```

### Wrapped with multiple parenthesis:

The following two snippets returns *exactly* the same results.

```
if ((((((((((((((((((((1)))))))))))))))))))) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

returns the same result as:

```
if (1) {
   printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

## Expression in `if` statement

Within your given `if` statement, you must have an expression that resolves to either true or false value. Please refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5k6t6kf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) page for example of expression.

Comment: I am aware of that, I mean what does (1) mean?

Comment: In this case, the parentheses are redundant.

Comment: In that case, why do I see so many init methods with double sets of parentheses?

Comment: @Fogmeister double parentheses are used for readability purposes. We use double parentheses in init methods to distinguish the *assignments* and simple *expressions*. For example, `if ((a = 5))` reads better than `if (a = 5)`.