# What do you call doing assignment in a conditional?

Tags: objective-c, c, conditional-statements, variable-assignment, terminology

Is there a special name for doing assignment in a conditional?  Here is an example of what I am asking about in C:

```
// Assume a and b have been previously defined and are compatible types
if( (a = b) ) {  // <- What do you call that?
  //do something
}
```

A couple friends of mine and I are convinced that there is a name for it, and some other people have agreed that there is one, but we can't find it anywhere. Has anyone here ever heard a term for it?

Comment: If I see code like that I tend to call it a "mistake". It usually was meant to be `a==b`. But it can be intentional, too.

Comment: @Yunnosch Haha, you beat me to it. If it's intentional, it's best to signify that with double parens as in `if ((a = b))`. GCC and Clang both have a `-Wparentheses` option that can warn you if you do assignment inside a conditional without the double parens.

Comment: It's called "optional unwrapping" in Swift. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that an assignment is intentional, there is no special name for this. C language specification places a very weak requirement on the controlling expression of an `if` statement:

> **6.8.4.1-1:** The controlling expression of an if statement shall have scalar type.

An assignment expression satisfies this requirement, as long as `a` and `b` are scalar. An implicit comparison to zero is performed on the result of this assignment:

> **6.8.4.1-2:** In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0. In the else form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0.

Note that compilers would issue a warning when they see an assignment like that, because missing second `=` is a common source of errors. [You can prevent these warnings using parentheses, as described in this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15379730/335858).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn’t really have a name, though people do call it various things. If the code follows your question:

```
if( a = b )...
```

then common terms are: *bug*, *error*, etc. However if `b` is not a variable but an expression, e.g. as in the common C patterns:

```
if( (c = getchar()) != EOF )...
while( *q++ = *p++ )...
```

then it might be called an *idiom*, *pattern*, etc.

Comment: if( a = b ) is a legitimate construct, although usually it's written as a mistake

Comment: @JooseppiLuna - exactly, it is valid code but is probably rarely what was intended hence why people often call it *bug*, *error*, or *mistake*...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if it has a name but I’d call it “useful feature that nobody understands”.
It is very useful indeed.
We can consider it a slang.

In C++ for example you can use this by declaring a variable directly, and this is useful for safety checks:

if (Object *a = takeObject()) {
        // a is not nullptr
   }

Or when I don’t want to repeat a statement in a loop:

```
while (a = next()) {

}
```

Instead of:

```
a = next();
while (a) {

   a = next();
}
```

But commonly these are just mistakes which compilers like gcc and clang give warnings about (and they force you to put an horrible double tuple to silence the warning ew!).